# What is the meaning of “le titi parisien”?

Tags: expressions, sens

What is the meaning of the colloquial French expression “*le titi parisien*”?  I've googled this several times, and while several answers come up, as a moderately fluent French speaker they don't “feel” right to me.  Since this is a question of “argot,” the nuance has to be just right, hence I'm coming here for insight from live humans.

Comment: Welcome to FL&U! What doesn't feel right in the [Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titi_parisien) for example?

Comment: It is also mentioned in Papillon, on page 258, which I am currently reading a fantastic read by the way
It refers to " A genuine Parisian titi - a tough, a wide boy" he was called Titi la Belote, because he was a wonderful Belote player, in his own words
Papillon by Henri Charriere, the true story of Papillon, I can't put the book down !

Answer (score 1):

I think the best English equivalent for it is *urchin*, as in *a street urchin*. Bear in mind that the quintessential *titi parisien* is Victor Hugo's Gavroche.

In *Dictionnaire des locutions françaises*, *un titi* (*pop*.) is given the following grammatical explanation:

> Le mot est sans doute de formation enfantine, un redoublement de
>   [pe]*tit*.

Comment: Do you think one could use it of an adult?  As in, "lui, c'est un titi parisien," meaning "he's a real Parisian."  A more colorful way of saying "c'est un vrai parisien."  Or is it too literally linked to childhood (urchinhood)?  Thanks.

Comment: It is exclusively used of children. But only in a historical context (specifically the 19th century).

Answer (score 1):

[According to the TLF dictionary](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=4010866695;r=1;nat=;sol=1;), le *titi parisien* is a 'typical' parisian kid. Like *Gavroche*, as Indoxica said in his answer, *un gavroche* being a synonym of *un titi parisien* according to the same dictionary.

This kid doesn't exist anymore though. This expression refers to kids of the mid/late 19th century.

Answer (score 1):

As a French, please allow me to answer your question, backing up on the French wikipedia that seems complete.

> Titi parisien est une expression familière, en France, pour désigner un « enfant de Paris », déluré, dégourdi et farceur, dont l'archétype est le personnage de Gavroche dans le roman Les Misérables de Victor Hugo ; puis, par extension, un adulte issu des classes populaires parisiennes.

A "Titi parisien" is a colloquial expression, in France to define a "child of Paris", resourceful, bright, and a practical joker, the archetype of which is the Gavroche character in "les Misérables" by Victor Hugo; then, consequently, an adult from popular classes in Paris.

You may Google "Titi parisien" and look at the pictures. All those with a cap on represent the titi parisien I grew up knowing.

Answer (score 0):

That's what wikipedia says about the expression, but actually what we call "titi parisien" is also the patois/local dialect that used to be talked in 1920-30 in Paris with expressions like "meszigues/teszigues/seszigues" as to say "moi/toi/lui". But that's a parisian thing (aa)

Comment: My wife, who is from Paris, has used the expression "avec une voix de titi parisiene" to describe a middle aged woman she encountered.