# Does this site include questions for Louisiana French?

Tags: étymologie

I wanted to add information pertaining to the term "titi" but it said I was restricted and I didn't know if this site included Louisiana French as I've been told it's, not the same, to put it nicely.

My adopted Aunt who was creole told me the term meant "little aunt".

She had no children of her own and I was the only child that she had call her this (all others used "maw maw").

I was a kid so she didn't explain it any further but it's like an aunt that's not a real aunt from what I understand, in New Orleans, Louisiana and areas.

Comment: Hey hi! Regional or dialectal variants are [on topic](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The site is a [Q&A site](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour) so you can't just add info about a topic, but you can answer a preexisting question or ask one and answer it. There are 2 questions about the word _titi_ already, in a different context ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7958/26366), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6877/26366)). What you describe sounds a bit like a diminutive of [_auntie_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auntie) but I wouldn't know. Cheers!

Comment: Additionally you should take a look at the French Language **Meta** forum which is part of Stack Exchange.